# Terraform + AWS S3 + Python: AccessDenied when calling the PutObject operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, boto3, cloudposse

I'm using Terraform to Create and S3 Private Bucket with IAM user & Keys to access to this Bucket. Here is my Terraform code.

```
module "s3_bucket" {
  source  = "cloudposse/s3-bucket/aws"
  version = "4.0.0"
  name    = local.bucket_name

  acl                = "private"
  enabled            = true
  user_enabled       = true
  force_destroy      = true
  versioning_enabled = true
  sse_algorithm      = "AES256"

  block_public_acls             = true
  allow_encrypted_uploads_only  = true
  allow_ssl_requests_only       = true
  block_public_policy           = true
  ignore_public_acls            = true
  cors_configuration            = [
    {
       allowed_origins = ["*"]
       allowed_methods = ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "HEAD", "DELETE"]
       allowed_headers = ["Authorization"]
       expose_headers  = []
       max_age_seconds = "3000"
    }
  ]

  allowed_bucket_actions        = ["s3:*"]
  lifecycle_configuration_rules =  []
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "s3_private_bucket_secret" {
  depends_on              = [module.s3_private_bucket]
  name                    = join("", [local.bucket_name, "-", "secret"])
  recovery_window_in_days = 0
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "s3_private_bucket_secret_credentials" {
  depends_on    = [module.s3_private_bucket]
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.s3_private_bucket_secret.id
  secret_string = jsonencode({
    KEY    = module.s3_private_bucket.access_key_id
    SECRET = module.s3_private_bucket.secret_access_key
    REGION = module.s3_private_bucket.bucket_region
    BUCKET = module.s3_private_bucket.bucket_id
  })
}
```

After running above code, i can a new user has been created in IAM with name `x-rc-bucket` with access key and secret same as stored in Secret manager and has policy attached as

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::x-rc-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::x-rc-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then i'v a simple python scripts which try to upload a file to s3 bucket using keys from above secret manager;

```py
import os
import boto3

image = "x.jpg"
s3_filestore_path = "images/x.jpg"
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(image)
content_type_dict = {
    ".png": "image/png",
    ".html": "text/html",
    ".css": "text/css",
    ".js": "application/javascript",
    ".jpg": "image/png",
    ".gif": "image/gif",
    ".jpeg": "image/jpeg",
}
content_type = content_type_dict[file_extension]
s3 = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version="s3v4"),
    region_name="eu-west-3",
    aws_access_key_id="**",
    aws_secret_access_key="**",
)
s3.put_object(
    Body=image, Bucket="x-rc-bucket", Key=s3_filestore_path, ContentType=content_type
)
```

It throws an error `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`.

What I'm looking is that every bucket should have it's own keys and could be accessible to that specific keys only.

Comment: If the bucket is private, you need to have a suitable S3 bucket policy which will allow user to access it.

Comment: Isn't the policy it created is right that is attached with user `x-rc-bucket`.

Comment: I wasn't sure from what you have written in the question. Is that policy assigned to the IAM user or the bucket?

Comment: Policy is assigned to IAM user.

Comment: Yup, so I think you need to add a bucket policy, but I have no idea how that module works, so it might be worth investigating.

Comment: Isn't the `allowed_bucket_actions` doing the same?

Comment: I don't think so, but I looked at the module code and it seems it's enforcing the secure transport by default, so you need to add at least `ServerSideEncryption='AES256'` to the `put_object` call.

Comment: Cool, it works now. thanks

Comment: @MarkoE a bucket policy isn't needed. The bucket policy and the user's IAM policy will be combined to determine if the user can access the bucket. The IAM policy is all that is needed.

Comment: @MarkoE also, the policy enforcing secure transport just means you have to connect to S3 using HTTPS instead of HTTP. It is totally unrelated to the server-side encryption algorithm. Also, that module should be setting the server-side encryption algorithm as a default on the bucket, specifically so that you *don't* have to specify that in every PutObject request.

Comment: @MarkB yeah, I didn't really look into the module code immediately, thanks for clarifying the rest.